# Passing django static file's path prefix into Ember.js template

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js, handlebars.js

when users come in the web app, django will render an index page contains all the Ember files and precompiled template(.hbs), that means the only port between client and server is the index page.

so the path prefix I use in django like:

```
<script src="{% static "js/vendor/ember-1.3.2.js" %}"></script>
```

**can not be recongnized** when I render .hbs pages made by Ember (because the templates are not controlled by django anymore). But I still need the static resources in server.

if not to use cdn or direct link, how can I make Ember templates get the resources?

maybe passing the path prefix by using handlebar helper?

Comment: Django Ember help integrates Ember.js in Django. https://github.com/noirbizarre/django-ember